# "reasonable" use of web APIs to sync data

Tags: api, web-applications, asana

My goal is to synchronize a web-application with an internal database.  The web-application has a public API, but in order to fully synchronize the two sources I would need to make around 2000 separate API calls every time.  My instinct tells me that this is excessive and possibly irresponsible, but I lack the experience to know for sure.

In this particular case the web-application is [Asana](http://www.asana.com), but I've encountered similar situations before with other services.  Is there any way to know if you're abusing a service through excessive API calls?  I know I'm not going to DOS a company like Asana, but I can't shake the feeling that there must be a better way than making ~150k requests per day.

The only other option I can think of is to update the web-service only when I know there's been a change in the database, but I'll lose a lot of capability that way.

I apologize for the subjectivity of this question, but I'm really hoping that someone can explain if there's any kind of etiquette that's expected when using public APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

This is an excellent question, or rather set of questions.

You are designing a system that will repeatedly make requests for every object. What will happen as the number of objects grows? Even if your initial request rate were reasonable, this would suffer problems with scalability. A more scalable solution is one that scales with the number of **changes** in the system. This will also grow over time, but much more slowly - the number of changes a single user can make per day is relatively constant, but the total number of objects they've created over time grows and grows. So my first piece of advice would be to avoid doing things this way, and instead find a way to detect changes and just act on those. It would be interesting to know why you feel you'll lose capability by taking this approach.

Now, I happen to know that the Asana API does not *currently* provide you with any friendly mechanism to just detect changes in the system. This is a commonly requested feature and we are looking into it, though I unfortunately cannot promise a delivery date. So you might be left with no choice but to poll our system for now.

As for being polite to the API, many service providers set limits on their API usage to prevent accidental or malicious use of the API from impacting the service to their other customers -- Asana is no exception. Sometimes these limits are published, other times not, and there is no standard limit: it all depends on the service. But it is very thoughtful of you to be curious about service limitations.

That said, 150k requests per day is, for the Asana API, kind of a lot. If all of our API users gave us that much traffic, we might be serving more requests per day than Google Web Search, and we're not quite that scalable yet. :) Technically, sometimes, we might handle requests at that volume from a single user.

If you must poll, try to poll on intervals like 15 minutes. But please do not poll your entire workspace on this time period; it's likely to be too much traffic/data. We're working on trying to provide you with a better solution.

If you do happen to make too many requests of the Asana API, you will get back HTTP status code 429 instead of your desired response; you can read more about that here (https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors).

Comment: Thank you very much Greg. That was extremely helpful and you answered all of my questions.  I will take your advice.

My concerns about losing capability were based on the assumption that I couldn't detect changes in Asana with the API.  I can detect changes in our own system though, and that will suffice for now.

Thank you again.

Comment: I'm one of those developers waiting for the ability to get only changed data via the API. Right now I poll Asana every 20-25 minutes for everything in my workspace - throttling it of course to comply with their limitations and handling 429 codes properly.